# Implementar el menú "Abrir con" en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, epub

Estoy haciendo un lector de EPUB en Android Studio con Java y necesito que si el usuario selecciona un archivo EPUB fuera del programa pueda aparecer la opción de abrirlo con el mismo programa.

Sería algo parecido a esto:

[image: Captura del menú de selección "Abrir con"]

Para así poder abrir directamente la actividad de lectura y guardar los datos del libro que necesito.

Tampoco sé exactamente como manejar exactamente la información que tengo que recibir una vez seleccionada mi aplicación en el menú,
lo único que se es que tengo que manejar un `URI` pero no sé con exactitud como sacar el `path` de él.

Ahora estoy intentando documentarme sobre el [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider) y el [Cómo abrir archivos con el framework de acceso al almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) según la documentación oficial de Android Studio.

Edición:
Como extensión adjunto una pregunta que responde el cómo utilizar la URI que devuelve el menú con el archivo deseado por el usuario:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/576392/316277

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tan sencillo como crear una URL personalizada definida mediante filtros en el manifiesto de tu aplicación. Si dos o más aplicaciones tienen un filtro coincidente es cuando aparece el menú para abrir que muestras. Más información: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters . También tienes una guía para agregarlos usando el asistente App Links Assistant de Android Studio 2.3 aquí: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Comment: En particular, el filtro `<intent-filter>` que buscas sería usando `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.epub" />` para abrir los archivos con extensión `.epub` y `<data android:scheme="file" />` para indicar que sean archivos locales. También deberías usar `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` para la acción `android.intent.action.VIEW`. Mírate esta documentación: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Receiving

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, agrega más información para entender lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es definir filtros de Intención (Intent filters) tal y como se muestra en la documentación [(ver)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) para la acción `android.intent.action.VIEW`.

Dentro de tu `<activity>` debes agregar este `<intent-filter>` tras el que viene por defecto:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content"
          android:mimeType="application/epub+zip" />
</intent-filter>
```

Quedando algo como:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="content"
              android:mimeType="application/epub+zip" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

Puedes ver más combinaciones de `<data>` en la documentación [(ver)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element):

```
<data android:scheme="string"
      android:host="string"
      android:port="string"
      android:path="string"
      android:pathPattern="string"
      android:pathPrefix="string"
      android:pathSuffix="string"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="string"
      android:mimeType="string" />
```

Extra: para obtener la ruta al archivo debes obtener los datos que recibe la intención. Este es un ejemplo para obtener los datos sin procesar:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
textView.setText(getIntent().getDataString());
```

Aunque lo habitual es que hagas uso de [`getIntent().getData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getData()) y luego [`getPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getPath()).

Por ejemplo:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto2);
String ruta = getIntent().getData().getPath();
ruta = ruta.substring(ruta.indexOf(":") + 1);
textView1.setText(ruta);
File file = new File(ruta);
textView2.setText(file.exists() ? "Existe" : "No existe");
```

Tienes la aplicación que he desarrollado para probar este código en el siguiente repositorio de GitHub:

- https://github.com/ojgarciab/android-open-epub

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero...
no me termina de quedar claro la creación del URL, se supone que tengo que introducir una dirección, pero no entiendo el cómo si no tengo web a la que acceder, igual puede ser culpa mía por no entender la documentación.

Comment: Los filtros sirven para que al visitar una URL o abrir un archivo cargue una de las intenciones (`Intent`) de tu aplicación. Depende de cómo configures el filtro será una URL o un archivo. Te he puesto el ejemplo para reaccionar a un archivo. Si quieres que también lo haga a páginas webs o URLs que contentan archivos `.epub` entonces habría que agregar un nuevo filtro para ello. Tu aplicación puede definir tantos filtros como desees y abrir tantos tipos de archivos o patrones URL como desees.

Comment: Acabo de descargarme la última versión de Android Studio para probar el código que te he compartido y he visto que han cambiado cosas desde la última vez que hice este tipo de tareas. Por ejemplo, en versiones de Android modernas se usa `content` como esquema en vez de `file` y, además, no he conseguido hacer funcionar el patrón de archivo con el esquema `content`, por lo que he cambiado el filtro al tipo mime. Ahora me cuentas si te funcionó esta última modificación.

Comment: El filtro está bien, pero tengo problemas para utilizar la Uri, estoy haciendo tests en el repositorio clonado que publicaste y no logro sacar una ruta válida para comenzar la lectura. Tanto si utilizo `uri.getPath()` como `uri.toString()`los resultados terminan siendo: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A31` o `/document/msf:31`

Comment: en el repo que me pasaste tambien parece pasar lo mismo, cuando seleccionas un `EPUB` siempre marca que no existe

Comment: Esa URI es de un [proveedor de documentos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider). Para acceder a ellos debes usar el marco de trabajo (framework) de acceso al almacenamiento (en el enlace anterior accederás a la documentación). ¿Quieres también un ejemplo de uso? Por favor, agrega toda esa información que solicitas nueva a la pregunta (editándola).

Comment: Por cierto, aunque aún no sepas abrir ese tipo de URIs, tu aplicación ahora es capaz de abrirse cuando quieres abrir un EPUB en un navegador de archivos o al descargarlos con el navegador, ¿cierto?

Comment: Mientras tanto te recomiendo que vayas mirando [`openFileDescriptor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Si, ahora el programa puede abrir archivos desde el navegador de archivos y otras aplicaciones como Telegram. Si pudieras poner un ejemplo de uso seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Creo que lo más lógico sería, para que otros usuarios pudieran encontrar la respuesta si la buscan, que crearas una nueva pregunta dónde expliques que deseas convertir una URI de un SAF (storage access framework) a un recurso de tipo `File` o una corriente de entrada ([`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) por ejemplo) o lo que necesites para abrir y trabajar con el archivo. Eso sí, para evitar que la cierren o te puntúen negativo, esta vez comparte el código de lo que has intentado (por ejemplo, el que te he proporcionado yo).