# Sacar datos del URI de un SAF

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo el menú de "Abrir con" de Android con el lenguaje Java. El problema está al momento de recolectar los datos.

El resultado del menú es una URI, pero cuando quiero sacar la ruta con
`uri.getPath()` o `uri.toString()` me retornan `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A31` y `/document/msf:31` respectivamente.

Éste es el código con el que estoy haciendo las pruebas:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="content"
               android:mimeType="application/epub+zip" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

**Main.java**

```java
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto2);
try {
    String ruta = getIntent().getData().getPath();
    ruta = ruta.substring(ruta.indexOf(":") + 1);
    textView1.setText(ruta);
    File file = new File(ruta);
    textView2.setText(file.exists() ? "Existe" : "No existe");
} catch (Exception e) {
    textView1.setText("Apertura normal");
    textView2.setText("de la aplicación");
}
```

El resultado siempre termina siendo *"No existe"*. Ahora estoy investigando sobre el [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver) y el [proveedor de documentos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener un `InputStream` con acceso al archivo al que apunta la URI puedes hacer uso del siguiente fragmento de código:

```
try {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    textView1.setText(getIntent().getData().getPath());
    InputStream file = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    /* Leemos el primer octeto del archivo:
        -1: hubo un error leyendo el archivo (no se abrió, está vacío, etc)
        75: código ASCII del primer carácter de un archivo EPUB
            (los dos primeros son "PK" al ser un ZIP)
    */
    textView2.setText(
            ((file.read() != -1) ? "Abierto" : "No abierto")
            + ": " + file.read()
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    textView1.setText("Apertura normal");
    textView2.setText("de la aplicación");
}
```

Existen diferentes llamadas de `ContentResolver` dependiendo de cómo quieras trabajar con el archivo. En este ejemplo he obtenido un `InputStream` haciendo uso de [`ContentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)).

Edición: tras el dato agregado en los comentarios, parece que la mejor forma de abrir el archivo es:

```
EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
Book book = epubReader.readEpub(
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(
        getIntent().getData()
    )
);
```

Ya que la función [`readEpub()`](http://siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/nl/siegmann/epublib/epub/EpubReader.html#readEpub(java.io.InputStream)) requiere un `InputStream` como parámetro de entrada, no es necesario obtenerlo a través de la ruta al archivo haciendo uso de un `new FileInputStream("/ruta/archivo.epub")`.

---

Tienes estas modificaciones funcionando en el siguiente repositorio de GitHub:

- https://github.dev/ojgarciab/android-open-epub

Comment: y como seria posible sacar la ruta apartir del `InputStream`?

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas la ruta? Es decir, ¿qué necesitas para abrir el archivo ePUB? ¿Estás usando alguna biblioteca de funciones existente o tu propia implementación?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con base en una librería llamada [epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib) y utilizo un código ajeno para la lectura modificado en cierta medida a mis necesidades

Comment: Listo. He editado la respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo de cómo abrir una URI de SAF con epublib.